Reopen request 74063
The question "Why was Cuba not colonized...?" is closed as too basic; it can be definitively answered by a single link to the relevant topic on Wikipedia or another standard reference source. If you are instead questioning the correctness of a reference source, please edit the post to supply a link and explain what you find unclear, or why you believe it to be wrong or incomplete.
I am really angry that my recent edits have not been successful in reopening the question.
3 months back I have requested this for reopening. The request has been deleted on February with no action. One of the reviewers has tried make an edit to the question to get it reopened. I have found that edit unsatisfactory. Then I have a conversation with the user in the comments. Their latest comment says:

I chose the feature "Edit and Re Open" in an attempt to help get your question re opened. My further comments were aimed at attempting to get you to edit your answer so that it could get re opened, but I guess I assumed that you had taken @justCal's comment to heart. Comments aren't somewhere for a debate. Best wishes.

So, I am waiting for a satisfactory edit to reopen this question. How to get this re-opened?
I have asked this question on December 29 when the History site is the Today's Featured Site. Look at the similar question about Japan. I try to duplicate every Japan post for Cuba and vice versa. And not only on StackExchange, I have asked so many questions on Quora. For example, look at this question I have asked. There also, I have tried to mimic the similar question about Japan.

I didn't participate in the voting on that, but there seems a pretty obvious difference: unlike Japan, Cuba was in fact colonized (Spain in fact colonized the **** out of it. The native Cubans and their language became extinct quite quickly). I don't see any possible way to make it similar to a question about the non-colonization of an uncolonized place.

@T.E.D. So, I am trying to ask why Cuba has been colonized by Spain, and not by others.

Thank you for bringing this to meta. This is the right place to discuss such issues, and will build a stronger community.
Re-open is a community decision.  The way to get a question re-opened is to persuade the community that the issues that led to closure have been addressed.  The key is to persuade.
Stack Exchange is built on the notion of trust in the community, and the implicit assumption that the community as a whole is wise enough to deal with situations where there is no objective criteria.  One possible explanation for the facts is that the community feels that the question is still too simple.
In any case, while we strive to make H:SE useful, it is not the only resource available. Some questions are better suited to other sites.

You should not have been editing a question that you've already accepted an answer to. In fact, you shouldn't have been making significant edits to a question that you have any answers to, accepted or not.
The recent edits actually made the, already vague, question worse by making it lack focus (there should only be a single question in each thread) and your acknowledgement that parts of the question were hypothetical scenarios just made the question even more off-topic.
If you wanted to ask a different question to the one you originally asked, you should have created a new question and left the original as it was.
